# how to add gesture recognizer to UIImage and UIButton of UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to attach a gesture recognizer on a button and on an image view in a dynamic tableView cell, but I get error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton
>   nameOfuserTappedWithGestureRecgonizer:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7ff34253f5a0'

```
protocol MediaTableViewCellDelegate: class {

    func didClickProfileImageOf(cell: MediaTableViewCell)
    func didClickProfileNameOf(cell: MediaTableViewCell)
}

class MediaTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    weak var delegate: MediaTableViewCellDelegate?

      @IBOutlet weak var mediaImageView: UIImageView! //the large image
      @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
      @IBOutlet weak var fullNameButton: UIButton!

       var tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage = UITapGestureRecognizer()
       var tapGestureRecognizerProfileName = UITapGestureRecognizer()



override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
         initialize()
    }
     private func initialize() {

      tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage.addTarget(self.profileImageView, action: #selector(MediaTableViewCell.imageTapped(gestureRecgonizer:)))
      self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage)

      tapGestureRecognizerProfileName.addTarget(self.shareButton, action: #selector(MediaTableViewCell.nameOfuserTapped(gestureRecgonizer:)))
      self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerProfileName)
   }

     func imageTapped(gestureRecgonizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.didClickProfileImageOf(cell: self)
  }

   func nameOfuserTapped(gestureRecgonizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     delegate?.didClickProfileNameOf(cell: self)
 }

}//end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title is misleading -- You are adding gesture recognizer to the UIElements, not the whole cell.

Buttons don't need a gesture recognizer since they subclass from UIControl.

```
private func initialize() {
    let imageTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(profileTapped))
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTapGesture)
    // imageviews by default aren't interactable
    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 

    fullNameButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func profileTapped() {
    delegate?.didClickProfileImageOf(cell: self)
}

@objc private func buttonTapped() {
    delegate?.didClickProfileNameOf(cell: self)
}
```

-- Updated per comment --

```
protocol MediaTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func mediaTableViewCell(_ cell: MediaTableViewCell, didClickProfileImage: Bool)
    func mediaTableViewCell(_ cell: MediaTableViewCell, didClickProfileName: Bool)
}
```

Comment: I have 3 types of prototype cells in my TableViewController. one cell handles the videos, another one the Images and the last one the text. It looks like I have to use different methods names because I get error when adopting the protocol in the TableViewController `Method 'didClickProfileImageOf(cell:)' with Objective-C selector 'didClickProfileImageOfCell:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Using Objc functions sometimes gets in the way of swift code. This is why delegate names are usually verbose. I would change the delegate names to something similar to how tableviews do it. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that you shouldn't add UIGestureRecognizer for a button, cuz it has already touch event.

Just add this code for button:

```
fullNameButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(some selector), for: .touchUpInside)
```

As for profileImageView add this lines of code:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(some selector)) 
profileImageView.isUserInteractionUnabled = true
profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the argument of `addTarget` with the caller of `addGestureRecognizer`.

The target of a gesture recognizer's `addTarget` is the class that implements the selector (the closure passed as `action`). Which in this case is `self`.

`addGestureRecognizer` adds the recognizer to the view itself.

So you want:

```
tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MediaTableViewCell.imageTapped(gestureRecgonizer:)))

self.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage)
```

Comment: I get error on second line when I tap on the image in the tableView `self.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerProfileImage)
 ` Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Does the error occur when you tap on the `imageView` or on loading?

Comment: See gist with the code that I have right now https://gist.github.com/bibscy/dc24db78177110e564783505e36aa83f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190534/discussion-between-bibscy-and-augusto-dias-noronha).